# Set Only First Position of Recyclerview as Header Layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create my own header layout in recyclerview without using any library. I have created the two layouts but now I'm confused how to set the first position as header and other positions scroll around it.

Here's my header layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/shareLayout"
android:layout_width="185dp"
android:layout_height="135dp"
android:layout_below="@id/trendingToolbar"
android:background="@color/black">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cameraShareIV"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/camera_white" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/cameraShareIV"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/share_pic_video"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/infoTxt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="@string/share_timeout_txt"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout contains an imageview which acts as a camera button for now. I want to select images from gallery and populate them around this layout head.
Here's the item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:minHeight="150dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="140dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/trending_imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_trophy"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/trending_imageView"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trending_userNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Jan Losert"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trending_itemsCountTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/badge_trending"
            tools:text="3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/trending_userNameTV"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my model class below:

```
public class TestTrends {

public String testImage;

public TestTrends() {
}

public TestTrends(String testImage) {
    this.testImage = testImage;
}

public String getTestImage() {
    return testImage;
}

public void setTestImage(String testImage) {
    this.testImage = testImage;
}
}
```

Here's my adapter code:

```
public class TrendingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = TrendingAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private Context context;
private List<Trending> itemList;
private List<TestTrends> trendsList;

private static final int HEADER = 0;
private static final int ITEMS = 1;

public TrendingAdapter(Context context, List<TestTrends> trendsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.trendsList = trendsList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    switch (viewType){
        case HEADER:
           v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.trending_header, parent, false);
           return new TrendingHeaderViewHolder(v);
        case ITEMS:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.trending_items_layout, parent, false);
            return new TrendingItemsViewHolder(v);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Trending tr = itemList.get(position);
    if (holder instanceof TrendingHeaderViewHolder){
        ((TrendingHeaderViewHolder) holder).cameraShareIV.setOnClickListener( view -> {
            TrendingFragment.newInstance().selectImage();
        });
    } else if (holder instanceof TrendingItemsViewHolder){
        TestTrends tre = trendsList.get(position);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(tre.getTestImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile_photo)
                .into(((TrendingItemsViewHolder) holder).testImgView);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //return itemList.size();
    return trendsList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
//        int vType = 0;
//        if (position == 0){
//            vType = 0;
//        }
//        return vType;
    // how do I set only first position to be header
    if (trendsList.get(position) == 0){

    }
}
}
```

I have added the parts of like `my activity code and the selectImage() from onBindViewHolder` to make this brief like below:

```
public class TrendingFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = TrendingFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar trendingToolbar;
private ImageView cameraSharePic;

private RecyclerView trendingRV;
private TrendingAdapter adapter;
private List<TestTrends> trendsList = new ArrayList<>();

public TrendingFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static TrendingFragment newInstance() {
    TrendingFragment tf = new TrendingFragment();
    return tf;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    View tv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trending, container, false);

    initViews(tv);

    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(trendingToolbar);

    trendingToolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.trending_title));
    trendingToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    trendingToolbar.setSubtitle(getResources().getString(R.string.trending_sub_title));
    trendingToolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

    trendingRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3,        GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    //trendingRV.setLayoutManager(glm);

    trendingRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    return tv;
}

private void initViews(View tv) {
    trendingToolbar = tv.findViewById(R.id.trendingToolbar);
    trendingRV = tv.findViewById(R.id.trendingRV);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.trending_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_all_friends:
            Log.d(TAG, "All Friends Selected");
            break;
        case R.id.action_custom:
            Log.d(TAG, "Custom Selected");
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void selectImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 20);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 20:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                String im = data.getData().toString();
                TestTrends tr = new TestTrends();
                tr.setTestImage(im);

                trendsList.add(tr);
                adapter = new TrendingAdapter(getActivity(), trendsList);
                trendingRV.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            break;
    }

}
}
```

So can someone explain to me how to select the right viewtype in `getItemViewType() for general multiple views cases` and also how to set `only the first position as header`.
Thanks, I have added the full Java code. Am I setting the adapter in the right place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your goal could be achieved by some changing in `onBindViewHolder`, `getItemCount` and `getItemViewType` methods:

1. Remove `Trending tr = itemList.get(position);` from `onBindViewHolder` and apply an offset to getting data from a collection if a holder is an instance of `TrendingItemsViewHolder`

   ```
   TestTrends tre = trendsList.get(position - 1);
   ```
2. Add an offset to your item count size

   ```
   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return trendsList.size() + 1;
   }
   ```
3. Make your `getItemViewType` always return HEADER on position 0 and ITEMS otherwise.

   ```
   @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       return position == 0 ? HEADER : ITEMS;
   }
   ```

**UPDATE:**

Here is how your adapter could look like with proper click handling

```
 public class TrendingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int HEADER = 0;
    private static final int ITEM = 1;

    private final List<TestTrends> data;
    private final HeaderClickListener headerClickListener;

    public TrendingAdapter(List<TestTrends> data, HeaderClickListener headerClickListener) {
        this.data = data;
        this.headerClickListener = headerClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? HEADER : ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size() + 1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        switch (viewType){
            case HEADER:
                v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.trending_header, parent, false);
                return new HeaderViewHolder(v, headerClickListener);
            default:
                v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.trending_items_layout, parent, false);
                return new ItemViewHolder(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == ITEM) {
            TestTrends testTrends = trendsList.get(position - 1);
            ((ItemViewHolder)holder).bind(testTrends);
        }
    }

    interface HeaderClickListener {
        void onHeaderClicked();
    }

    static class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        HeaderViewHolder(View itemView, final HeaderClickListener headerClickListener) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> headerClickListener.onHeaderClicked());
        }
    }

    static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView testImgView;

        ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //REPLACE yourId WITH REAL IMAGE VIEW ID
            testImgView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
        }

        void bind(TestTrends testTrends) {
            Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(testTrends.getTestImage())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile_photo)
                    .into(testImgView);
        }
    }
}
```

Also you should add an interface implementation to your fragment

```
public class TrendingFragment extends Fragment implements TrendingAdapter.HeaderClickListener
```

Here is an implementation

```
@Override
public void onHeaderClicked() {
    selectImage()
}
```

And finally pass `this` as `headerClickListener`, when creating adapter

```
adapter = new TrendingAdapter(trendsList, this);
```

Comment: It's not working bro. I have edited the question to reflect where I'm setting the adapter. Pls take a look

Comment: Strange, I've double checked it and it works for me. Looks like there is no problems with the place where you're setting the adapter. Pls, double check, that you really got an onActivityResult call and there is a request code 20 with a result code RESULT_OK and you 100% calling setAdapter. Because if you don't see anything populated in your RV, perhaps the adapter was not set at all

Comment: Bro, this might be too much to ask, but can you zip your files and post them as a drive link?

Comment: It shows the header now. But when it's clicked, the app crashes pointing to the call to startActivitvityForResult line. Says sth about being attached to an activity, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Andromeda Seems that your click listener has wrong implementation. Avoid setting click listeners in `onBindViewHolder` and handle clicks inside adapter at all. It's better to set it in ViewHolder's constructor and pass the click event with a custom interface to a fragment/activity that contains your recycler view.

Comment: I have set the uri from gallery to my model image and logged it in terminal. It logs the image path but nothing is shown in recyclerview. Let me edit the question so you can see too and sorry, for the late response...laptop issues. Thanks

Comment: I still have not found a way to complete this but I will accept this answer as it's the closest to what I was looking for. Thanks for the effort.